# How can I switch between test, UAT and production servers to which my Android app connects to?

Tags: android, mobile, production-environment

We are developing a Phonegap app (this problem is applicable for all mobile platforms, native or hybrid) which needs to interact with a set of web services which were also developed by us.

We use test, UAT and production/live servers for web services.  At times for experimental or for debug purposes we need our mobile app to switch between these servers.

In order to do that we have to modify the URL of the web servers by switching it from say live to test server and recompile the app.  We want to do this switching without recompiling the app.  At times we have to reproduce certain scenarios that the app with customer and hence we use this approach.  For ensuring accuracy we do not want to recompile the code just to switch the servers.

The tricks that I have are:

1. Have a configurable setting which can be edited by the user of the mobile app, where the URL of the server can be changed from live to test server. Drawback: I do not want the end users fiddling with this or even knowing the server's URL.  For this purpose I have do lengthy workarounds which are not desirable.
2. We can have the app reading the URL from a known text file from the file system of the mobile, which the user can edit to switch. Again even though not explicit, the drawbacks of the above method is still present.
3. Since I am connecting the mobile app through Wi-Fi I can redirect the target in my router setting. But this requires co-operation from other departments and will fail if frequently asked for.
4. Modifying the `etc/hosts` file in mobile to reroute the destination. Drawback it requires root privileges and I am not ready to root yet.

**My question:**
What is the development strategy that is followed in these situations where I want a mobile app to switch its server's URL without recompiling and user providing the input?

**Update**:
Since the app might have been released for live use, I cannot play with redirection at server as it will affect all users. I have the redirection to happen only for my team/testers for the same version of the app that is being used concurrently by live users.

Answer (score 0):

Consider runtime server check.
Use a static server api that return the designed server path (test,production,UAT etc)

App on init make that api call. And keep the designed server path for runtime use

Comment: What if tester find a bug in UAT and want to try to reproduce that one in production - how to reconfigure dynamically the app from UAT to production or vice versa?